# How to break down an object functionality in a test in Scala

Tags: scala, unit-testing, testing, mocking

This a generic question for a common problem, let's describe it as easy as I can... Suppose I have:

```
class A {
  def x() = //do something with e
  def e() = //do something else
}
```

basically a simple class where method `x()` is calling method `e()`. The logic of x() and e() are pretty complex. So it's not practical to test them in integration (by calling `x()` and asserting). It's easier to test `x()` and `e()` separately, with some mocking. So I could go and do:

```
abstract class A {
  def x() = {
    /* do */
  }

  def e()
}

object A {
  def eImpl() = {}

  def apply(): A = new A() {
    override def e(): Unit = eImpl()
  }
}
```

and then test the behaviour of x() with:

```
class ASpec extends FlatSpec {

  def eImpl() = {}

  def mockedA(inner: A => Unit) = {
    inner(new A {
      override def e(): Unit = ??? //some behaviour to help test, a mock, etc..
    })
  }

  "x in A" should "do this an that" in mockedA { a =>

  }

  "eImpl" should "do something else" in {

  }
}
```

but... This assumes that A() in the companion object binds the right implementation. And all in all it all seems a bit verbose to me maybe. So what could be a way to structure this class to be tested reliably and make sure that the instances have the right implementations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't `spy` what you're looking for?

Assuming

```
class A {
    def x(): String = "Hello" + e()
    def e(): String = "World"
}
```

you can mock `e()` and `x()` separately:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.scalatest.mockito.MockitoSugar
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}
class ASpec extends WordSpec with Matchers with MockitoSugar {
    "Spy test" should {
        "mock only e" in {
            val a = spy(new A())
            when(a.e()).thenReturn("Mock")
            a.x() shouldBe "HelloMock"
            a.e() shouldBe "Mock"
        }
        "mock only x" in {
            val a = spy(new A())
            when(a.x()).thenReturn("Yo" + a.e())
            a.x() shouldBe "YoWorld"
            a.e() shouldBe "World"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes spy just does that, it proves also that the x is calling a.

Comment: I noticed that if e is defined like def e() = ??? when mocking it in a spy object, mockito will throw NPE in the when(mock.e()) call

Answer (score -1):

You can do this without introducing mock frameworks by using traits.

```
trait A {
  def x() = "Hello " + e()
  def e() = "World"
}

class TestAX extends A {
  override def x() = super.x()
  override def e() = "Mock"
}

class TestAE extends A {
  override def x() = "Mock " + e()
  override def e() = super.e()
}

"x in A" should "do this and that" {
  val testA = new TestAX()
  assert(testA.x() == "Hello Mock")
  assert(testA.e() == "Mock")
}

"e in A" should "do something else" in {
  val testA = new TestAE()
  assert(testA.x() == "Mock World")
  assert(testA.e() == "World")
}
```

TestAX uses the production version of x() and overrides e() to either do nothing or provide information for the test to use (could be a constant value or something).

That said, if e() and x() are both fairly complex I would recommend breaking them down into smaller pieces, so you're not testing "do all the work -> did all the work get done?"

Comment: the problem was to make sure that x is actually calling e, so I am able to test them independently. Your solution does not prove that x is calling e. It allows separate testing but for what is worth x can really call by mistake another method e1() that you left around while refactoring and you would not know.

Comment: Also why do you need to declare two classes? The same effect can be achieved by using two anonymous implementations in the "do something" in new TraitAX {...}

Comment: I declared 2 classes to be explicit for other readers more than anything, these could be anonymous subclasses. My point was that you can accomplish what is done in the accepted answer without introducing new test dependencies. Rather than `{}`, implement the function that's not being tested with some constant value (like `"Mock"`) and the assertions are identical to those in the accepted answer. I'll update my answer to be cleaer.

Comment: The reason your answer is wrong are actually 2 reasons: 1) no need to override if then you call super. 2) your solution does not prove that, if x() makes use of e(), x is actually calling e(), that's what was asked in the question. Your test won't be able to say that.

Comment: also mocking doesn't necessarily mean to introduce test dependencies, can be done with adhoc classes. It's just a testing tecnique.